# QueryDSL: Query by composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

I have an entity `Parte` with a composite primary key. These are the columns:

- `codabast`
- `codejerc`
- `codparte`

I have annotated my entity with `@IdClass(PartePK.class)`. Now, to perform a query by primary key, I do this:

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);

query.from(qParte).where(qParte.codabast.eq(myCodAbast)
    .and(qParte.codejerc.eq(myCodEjerc)
    .and(qParte.codparte.eq(myCodParte))));

Parte p = query.singleResult(qParte);
```

Is it needed to do it field by field? Or does exist a way to query by primary key?

I would like something like this:

```
PartePK primaryKey = new PartePK(3, 4, 6);
query.from(qParte).byId(primaryKey);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using `entityManager.find`?